# Why is Roslyn generating a > comparison instead of a != one here?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I was playing around with the C# compiler on TryRoslyn recently, and I came across a strange problem where an inequality check was getting converted into a greater-than one. Here is the repro code:

```
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        if (Foo() != 0 || Foo() != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        }
    }

    private int Foo() => 0;
}
```

and here is the code that gets generated by the decompiler:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        bool flag = this.Foo() != 0 || this.Foo() > 0; // this should be an != check
        if (flag)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
        }
    }
    private int Foo()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[Here's](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3aywAMxhiAYnz6SYAQgC8MAAwwAPoZir1UnfokzZbFrYcM+EEHyKoAdAHUATmDQAMpCoYgBEABJgmqESOI4wAL42icnJuH48VGgwkMimahraAHz6OAlAA) the link to the repro. Why does Roslyn do this; is it a bug?

Some observations I've made after playing around with the code for a while:

- This only happens with the last boolean expression in the condition. For example if you add another `||` statement, it will only happen with the last call to `Foo()`.
- It also only happens with 0, specifically; if you substitute it for `1`, or some other number, it won't happen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The decompiled code is wrong; this is a bug in the decompiler, not the compiler. The generated IL is correct. **Read the IL very carefully**. Do you see why the greater-than comparison is correct and the decompilation is wrong?

As for why this codegen only happens for the right hand side of the operator, that I do not recall.  If you want to go spelunking in the code generator it is here:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/CodeGen/EmitOperators.cs

You want method `EmitIsNonNullOrZero`.

Comment: Alright, I think I see what the problem is; the opcode is a `cgt.un`, which does an unsigned comparison, so the decompiled code should really be `(uint)this.Foo() > (uint)0` (which is true for all nonzero ints). Thanks for pointing that out.